# Local Notification When didEnterRegion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, ibeacon, estimote

I have the following code which work perfect when app terminated.

```
-(void)beaconManager:(id)manager didEnterRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{


    UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    notification.alertBody = @"TEST NOTIFICATION";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

}
```

**But When I do the following:**

```
-(void) createTestNotification {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    notification.alertBody = @"TEST";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

}
-(void)beaconManager:(id)manager didEnterRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{


        [self createTestNotification];

}
```

**It does not work ?** I only move my code to outside nothing else ? I know that the app will have only 5 sec when didEnterRegion get called but call this method will not take this time ?

**UPDATE 1:**

I just found out that the **region** `didEnterRegion` return is the one that I start **monitoring** not the one belong to the **beacon** that app just saw it.and I was going to use this **region** to get my custom msg depend on the **major&minor** for this region.

But it is not possible in my case , so I start **ranging** when `didEnterRegion` get called ,then in `didRangeBeacons` which return array of **beacons** I got the text msg that belong to this **beacon** from **localDataBase** **"depend on Major&minor"**

***And this is my Code :*** **this code work when in app in background and get notify but when app close never get notify ?**

```
-(void)beaconManager:(id)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{

   [self handelBeaconsNotification:beacons];

}

-(NSString *) getBeaconFromLocalData:(NSNumber *)regionMajor andRegionMin:(NSNumber *)regionMinor{


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Beacons"];
    NSArray *allRegions_id = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];
    [query whereKey:@"region_id" containedIn:allRegions_id];
    NSLog(@"%@",regionMajor);
    NSLog(@"%@",regionMinor);
    [query whereKey:@"major" equalTo:regionMajor];

    [query whereKey:@"minor" equalTo:regionMinor];

    [query fromLocalDatastore];

    NSArray *data = [query findObjects];

    return [[data objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"enter_message"];





}

-(void) handelBeaconsNotification:(NSArray *)beaconsArray{


    for (int i = 0 ; i<beaconsArray.count; i++) {

        NSString *currentBeaconKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",[beaconsArray[i] major],[beaconsArray[i] minor]];

        if ([beaconsDictionary valueForKey:currentBeaconKey] == nil) {

            NSMutableDictionary *dateDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [dateDic setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"StartVisit"];

            [dateDic setValue:nil forKey:@"EndVisit"];

            [beaconsDictionary setValue:dateDic forKey:currentBeaconKey];

            UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
            notification.alertBody = [self getBeaconFromLocalData:[beaconsArray[i] major] andRegionMin:[beaconsArray[i] minor]];
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
            notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

        }
    }

}
```

**Update 2:**
I just add **Log** to `didEnterRegion` and `didRangeBeacons` to find out that only the **NSLog** from `didEnterRegion` appear then the app look like it ***crash*** and the **log** from `didRangeBeacons` did not appear

```
Oct 11 00:27:25 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[220] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/76CE6FC9-46AA-4C5B-9F8C-F31C1F38CAD2 (sandbox)
Oct 11 00:27:26 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone Swipt[220] <Warning>: 111111111111111111111111
Oct 11 00:27:26 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone locationd[70] <Notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.swiptrewards.Swipt[0x8b1f][220]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Notice>: platform_thread_get_unique_id matched 6383
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[220] Swipt
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone assertiond[65] <Error>: assertion failed: 13A452: assertiond + 60449 [BDEA3ABF-EF9E-34B9-A166-8AE775484A67]: 0x3
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone Unknown[65] <Error>: 
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.swiptrewards.Swipt[0x8b1f]' crashed.
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 13250595064: id=com.swiptrewards.Swipt pid=220, state=0
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Warning>: report not saved because the limit of 25 for 109_Swipt logs has been reached.
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Notice: This report is abbreviated for syslog inclusion because it could not be saved to disk.
    Symbolication may be possible by manually cleaning up and including the Binary Image section of a full report from this same device -- good luck!
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Process:             Swipt [220]
    Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E547BB5-F423-48DC-B013-B549C0AE6A0E/Swipt.app/Swipt
    OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  0
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
    0.484432     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025682aa1 TCP Conn 0x15ec9800 SSL Handshake DONE
    0.586995     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025682aa1 TCP Conn 0x15eb5080 SSL Handshake DONE
    0.666939     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025682aa1 TCP Conn 0x15eb6980 SSL Handshake DONE
    0.742367     CFNetwork                  0x00000000256829db TCP Conn 0x15ec9800 starting SSL negotiation
    0.742681     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257024cd TCP Conn 0x15ec9800 complete. fd: 13, err: 0
    0.742994     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257035cf TCP Conn 0x15ec9800 event 1. err: 0
    0.939516     CFNetwork                  0x000000002570364d TCP Conn 0x15ec9800 started
    0.983614     CFNetwork                  0x00000000256829db TCP Conn 0x15eb5080 starting SSL negotiation
    0.983989     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257024cd TCP Conn 0x15eb5080 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
    0.984285     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257035cf TCP Conn 0x15eb5080 event 1. err: 0
    1.050325     CFNetwork                  0x00000000256829db TCP Conn 0x15eb6980 starting SSL negotiation
    1.052768     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257024cd TCP Conn 0x15eb6980 complete. fd: 5, err: 0
    1.053148     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257035cf TCP Conn 0x15eb6980 event 1. err: 0
    1.282007     CFNetwork                  0x000000002570364d TCP Conn 0x15eb6980 started
    1.282007     CFNetwork                  0x000000002570364d TCP Conn 0x15eb5080 started
    1.294984     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257442df Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
    1.294984     CFNetwork                  0x00000000257442bb Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    1.294984     CFNetwork                  0x000000002578673b Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800cd24 0x37ff8000 + 85284
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380acb5a 0x380a9000 + 15194
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37fa4f50 0x37f5a000 + 307024
    3   Swipt                           0x003860a6 0xf0000 + 2711718
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x25e5fba8 0x25d6a000 + 1006504
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37813086 0x3780c000 + 28806
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36ff7e16 0x36fe1000 + 93718
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36ff78f6 0x36fe1000 + 92406
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37812f46 0x3780c000 + 28486
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x25d7326e 0x25d6a000 + 37486
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x25d72fdc 0x25d6a000 + 36828
    11  GraphicsServices                0x2f017af8 0x2f00e000 + 39672
    12  UIKit                           0x29fd817c 0x29f5f000 + 495996
    13  Swipt                           0x00116ab0 0xf0000 + 158384
    14  libdyld.dylib                   0x37f3d872 0x37f3b000 + 10354
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800e3c0 0x37ff8000 + 91072
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f249a6 0x37f14000 + 68006
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f16b2e 0x37f14000 + 11054
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ff9130 0x37ff8000 + 4400
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ff8f30 0x37ff8000 + 3888
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x25e224ec 0x25d6a000 + 754924
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x25e20872 0x25d6a000 + 747634
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x25d731e8 0x25d6a000 + 37352
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x25d72fdc 0x25d6a000 + 36828
    6   Foundation                      0x26b63d7c 0x26b58000 + 48508
    7   Swipt                           0x0032ef3e 0xf0000 + 2355006
    8   Foundation                      0x26c347fc 0x26b58000 + 903164
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380abc92 0x380a9000 + 11410
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380abc06 0x380a9000 + 11270
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a24 0x380a9000 + 2596
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x15ea11c0 :: NSOperation 0x15e933c0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ff9130 0x37ff8000 + 4400
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ff8f30 0x37ff8000 + 3888
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x25e224ec 0x25d6a000 + 754924
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x25e20872 0x25d6a000 + 747634
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x25d731e8 0x25d6a000 + 37352
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x25db3faa 0x25d6a000 + 303018
    6   Foundation                      0x26c1ecc4 0x26b58000 + 814276
    7   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f1f04e 0x37f14000 + 45134
    8   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f1802e 0x37f14000 + 16430
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x37f203dc 0x37f14000 + 50140
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x37f2024a 0x37f14000 + 49738
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e28 0x380a9000 + 3624
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ff9130 0x37ff8000 + 4400
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37ff8f30 0x37ff8000 + 3888
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x25e224ec 0x25d6a000 + 754924
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x25e20872 0x25d6a000 + 747634
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x25d731e8 0x25d6a000 + 37352
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x25d72fdc 0x25d6a000 + 36828
    6   CFNetwork                       0x256e40ae 0x2565c000 + 557230
    7   Foundation                      0x26c347fc 0x26b58000 + 903164
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380abc92 0x380a9000 + 11410
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380abc06 0x380a9000 + 11270
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a24 0x380a9000 + 2596
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 10:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 11:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 12:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 13:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 14:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800d92c 0x37ff8000 + 88364
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9e34 0x380a9000 + 3636
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a18 0x380a9000 + 2584
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 15 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    Thread 15:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3800cfb4 0x37ff8000 + 85940
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x25e27990 0x25d6a000 + 776592
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380abc92 0x380a9000 + 11410
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380abc06 0x380a9000 + 11270
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x380a9a24 0x380a9000 + 2596
Oct 11 00:27:27 Moe-Amleh-s-iPhone ReportCrash[221] <Error>: Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
        r0: 0x00000004    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x15eb25d0      r3: 0x00000000
        r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x15e81c60      r7: 0x4072cfb4
        r8: 0x15eb25d0    r9: 0x3ae01900     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000020
        ip: 0x0000005d    sp: 0x40724bec      lr: 0x25e27991      pc: 0x3800cfb4
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean when you say it works "when app terminated"?  Do both code snippets work when a beacon is detected when the app is terminated, or both?  And what is the state of the application on the phone when it doesn't work?

Comment: When testing code like this, add `NSLog` statements in the `didEnterRegion` method, then watch for these log lines in XCode as you trigger beacons.  You may find that the problem isn't with the notification, but that you aren't getting the beacon trigger.

Comment: both code worked when app in background and like you know when u close the app nothing will work ,  but  didEnterRegion well give u a view sec to run your code or do something , so i present local notification with static msg . but for me i need to get the msg from local database and when I call my method which get the msg and present the notification it does not work no notification appear "my code take less than 1 sec to get the msg , so i remove all my code and just present notification like u see but still not work ? @davidgyoung

Comment: @davidgyoung check update my Question ?

Comment: I suggest you add three NSLog lines, one in `didEnterRegion`, one in `didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` and one in `handelBeaconsNotification`.  Then, make sure you app does not detect the beacon -- that it thinks it is outside the region.  Then "close" your app with the task switcher, and connect it to your computer with XCode running.  In XCode, go to Window -> Devices -> (Select your device) then expand the log console on the bottom of the screen so you can see NSLog statements.  (Click the up arrow near the bottom-left).  Turn on a beacon and look for your log statements.  Which ones do you see?

Comment: @davidgyoung I did and it seems that the app crash before it didRangeBeacons get called ?

Comment: @davidgyoung solve it :)

Comment: obviously, you need to figure out what is causing that crash.  If it only happens when the app launches on beacon detection after being closed in the task switcher, then I'd suggest adding more and more NSLog statements and reproducing the issue until you can figure out exactly what line of the code causes the crash to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mmm i think you are using null region variables ,so make sure you send it correctly and do not use null variables for startRanging method.

When your app closed, all variables will be terminated so make sure that you pass it not null.

Comment: that actually solved my problem :D I called startRanging using global Varibale with null value.

Comment: I face this problem before , and i was like you , but after weeks with searching,,, i solved it  ;)

Comment: Mohammad Rabi how can I contact you, can you write your email in your profile